# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use ‘in’ operator to search for ‘length’ in jquery-1.11.1.js:583

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two JS files as shown below (page1.js) and (page2.js for reference included below). I am basically referring to the following JSON response while working :

```
{
    "webservice_status": {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "message": ""
    },

    "my_document_list": [{

            "doc1": "445",
            "doc2": "445",
            "doc3": "445",
            "doc4": "445",
            "content": "Some text here to display"
        }

    ]
}
```

Here is my `page1.js` related work:

```
$("#mydoclist").on('rowclick', function (event) {
            row = event.args.rowindex;
            datarow = $("#mydoclist").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
            var response = JSON.stringify(datarow, null, 10);
            var docID  = datarow["doc_id"];
            self.getMyDocumentContents(docID);

   });

this.getMyDocumentContents = function (contentID_) {

   var data = {
      doc_id: contentID_
   }

   app_.get(data, self.processContent, app_.processError, url_name);

}// End of getMyDocumentContents


this.processContent = function(data_,textStatus_,jqXHR_) {

      data_ = app_.convertResponse(data_,jqXHR_);
      console.log("Checking for actual data_ content:", data_); 
      console.log("Actual Data Length Check for data_ content:", data_.my_document_list.length); 

      // debugger;

      var collection = data_.my_document_list.length[0].content;
      console.log("Collection Check",collection);

      //debugger;

       var source = {
         localdata: collection,
         datafields: [{
         name: 'content',
         type: 'string'
       }],
      datatype: "array"
      };


      var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {

           loadComplete: function (records) {

                debugger;

                var html;

          //Get data
            var records = dataAdapter.records;
            console.log("Check for records:",records.length);
            var length = records.length;
            html = "<div style='margin: 10px;'><pre>" + records[0].content + "</pre></div>";
            $("#docContentPanel").jqxPanel('clearcontent');
            $("#docContentPanel").jqxPanel('append',html);

            },
            loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { },
            beforeLoadComplete: function (records) {

            }

           });

            // perform data binding
            dataAdapter.dataBind();

            var panel = $("#docContentPanel");
            var content = panel.html();
            panel.jqxPanel({ width: '750', height: '500', scrollBarSize: 20 });

 }// End of processContent
```

Here is my `page2.js` related work:

```
this.get = function (data_, done_, fail_, webServiceKey_) {

        // Lookup the requested web service URL
        var url = https://documentlookup.com:8443/getmydocuments;


        // Create the AJAX request.
        $_.ajax({
            data: data_,
            method: "GET",
            url: url
        })
        .success(done_)
        .error(fail_);
    };

// If the JSON data was returned with content type of "text/plain", parse as JSON before returning.
    this.convertResponse = function (data_, jqXHR_) {

        return (typeof(data_) === "object" ? data_ : JSON.parse(data_));

    };
```

Basically there is a list of rows displayed in a jqxgrid(not mentioned in the code above), when a user clicks on it
`$("#mydoclist").on('rowclick` gets called , which calls the following function:
`getMyDocumentContents` function: This function basically passes the `doc_id` inside data variable which is made
available for the following function:
`processContent:`
In this function, I am trying to show in jqxPanel the value of the `content`which is in  `my_document_list` array.

**Problem I am facing inside this function:**
As can be seen, there are debugger I placed at various places which are currently commented except at one place
which is just below this line `loadComplete: function (records) {`
I don’t get any error above this line `var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, { ,` however, as soon as
I place it inside it, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use ‘in’ operator to search for ‘length’ in jquery-1.11.1.js:583

Where length is a numerical number which keeps on changing depending upon the length of value of `content` in the above JSON response.
Could anyone tell me what’s going wrong? thanks in advance !
Just in case needed, here is the jQuery line #583 isArraylike function :

```
function isArraylike( obj ) {
    var length = obj.length,
        type = jQuery.type( obj );

    if ( type === "function" || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( obj.nodeType === 1 && length ) {
        return true;
    }

    return type === "array" || length === 0 ||
        typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj; // THIS is LINE 583 which throws error
}
```

Should I try changing the jQuery version?

Answer (score 0):

At `data_.my_document_list.length[0].content;` I think you need `data_.my_document_list[0].content;`.

`my_document_list` is an array and as such the array access should occur there.

Comment: Thanks. I did what you mentioned and it's still the same. I think I have mentioned wrong line in my post. Actual testing involves this line only `var collection = data_.my_document_list[0].content;`

Comment: Thanks for your time. Appreciated. I was able to fix the bug by modifying this line ` var collection = data_.my_document_list.length[0].content;` to ` var collection = data_.my_document_list.length;`